AWS Lambda + S3: Moving/Renaming a folder in S3 using Lambda
I need to be able to move/rename a folder inside S3 using a lambda function written in python. I have seen that it is possible to copy and then delete a file using the boto3 library but I cannot find a method of renaming a folder.
Example: bucket:/folder/ -> bucket:/renamedfolder/

What you have seen is correct, currently AWS does not support renaming an object in S3. To rename an object in S3, you need to copy the object to a new location with the desired name and then delete the original object.
Folder structure in S3:
S3 is an object storage service, not a file system. The concept of "folders" in S3 is an abstraction provided by the AWS Management Console to help users organize their objects visually. However, these "folders" don't actually exist as separate entities within S3.
For example, if you have an object with the path my-bucket/my-folder/my-file.csv, the full name (or key) of the object is my-folder/my-file.csv. The my-folder/ part is simply a prefix in the object's key. S3 organizes objects based on these prefixes, and in the S3 console, this is represented as a folder structure for ease of use. Nevertheless, S3 only sees it as an object with the key (file name) my-folder/my-file.csv but the folder does not exist as a separate it just part of the object's name.
Conclusion:
to rename a folder you have to rename all objects with that prefix
Example code:
EDIT thanks to comment from @jarmond code is adapted to hold over 1000 keys. As mention in the comments s3.list_objects_v2 only returns the first 1000 objects. If you have a prefix with more than 1000 keys you should consider this fact.
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def rename_prefix_in_many_objects(bucket_name, old_prefix, new_prefix, objects_keys):
    for obj in objects_keys :
        old_key = obj['Key']
        new_key = old_key.replace(old_prefix, new_prefix, 1)
        rename_s3_object(bucket_name, old_key, new_key)

def rename_s3_object(bucket_name, old_key, new_key):
    s3.copy_object(Bucket=bucket_name, 
                   CopySource={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': old_key}, 
                   Key=new_key)
    s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=old_key)

def rename_prefix_until_complete(bucket_name, old_prefix, new_prefix):
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(
        Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=old_prefix
    )

    # This for loop is because by default aws only returns 1000 files
    while response["IsTruncated"]:
        rename_prefix_in_many_objects(bucket_name, old_prefix, new_prefix, response['Contents'])
        response = s3.list_objects_v2(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            Prefix=old_prefix,
            ContinuationToken=response["NextContinuationToken"],
        )

bucket_name = "bucket"
old_prefix = "folder/"
new_prefix = "renamedfolder/"

s3_keys = rename_prefix_until_complete(bucket_name, old_prefix, new_prefix)


Just to be clear, the fact that object storage is flat and that “folders” are really just prefixes of the object name is not the reason why the S3 API has no rename operation. Although both are a consequence of the implementation of object storage.

@KonradRudolph I totally agree with your point. I will make it clearer in the answer.

Note that the folder entities can actually exist, though in the default case they do not. Specifically, any client can create an object whose key is "folder1/folder2/" to represent a folder. The AWS S3 console does this if you ask it to create a folder but, as you say, this is part of the S3 console's hierarchical abstraction.

Also, I think it's mildly confusing to say that "an object with the key my-bucket/my-folder/my-file.csv ..." when my-bucket is the bucket name and is not actually part of the key at all.

One comment on the proposed code: it will only copy/delete up to 1000 objects maximum. For the general case, it would need to implement pagination or use the resource-level Bucket's objects collection interface, which automates pagination.

@jarmod thanks for the comments. Specially for the miss understood between key and bucket (I have updated). I will make an update to the code with more than 1000 objects.

@jarmod, thanks for all the feedback. Updated everything
